# _vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata missing from https web service

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have to connect from VS2012 (or VS2017, same problem) to a java based web service that enables only TLS 1.2 with mutual certificate authentication. WSDL URL is for example https://example.com:8443/foo/bar?wsdl. I have added root certificate to my trusted root store, and client certificate with private key to my personal store, and I can download the WSDL file with Chrome (after the browser asks me for a certificate to connect to the service).

Problem is, I can't add the service reference in Visual Studio. The text that I get is "An error (Details) occurred while attempting to find services at 'https://example.com:8443/foo/bar?wsdl'". Clicking on Details brings the following text:

> There was an error downloading
>   'https://example.com:8443/foo/bar?wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://example.com:8443/foo/bar?wsdl'. Could
>   not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   'example.com:8443'. The request was aborted: Could not
>   create SSL/TLS secure channel. If the service is defined in the
>   current solution, try building the solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

It looks like Visual Studio got the main WSDL part but then asked for this .../$metadata adage, which does not exist, nor is it mentioned in the WSDL. How do I configure Visual Studio to consume the service as it is?

Note, I can download the WSDL file and add service reference from file, but I'd rather rely on Visual Studio to do that for me automatically, so that the next developer a year from now does not have to spend a day figuring out how to update the reference. Also, absolute path to WSDL file is saved in Reference.svcmap file, which is not ideal when sharing project via source control.

Comment: While the question is not strictly c# related, I'd like c# tag to be here, if it ever happens that some code is required, or just to attract more of the appropriate audience.

Comment: How are you adding the reference? Are going to: Add Service Reference --> Advanced --> Add Web Reference and entering the path to the WSDL there, then clicking Add Reference? I think the $metadata is likely referring to the schemas (xsd definitions a WSDL).

Comment: The same problem is happening with both (service reference and web service reference) when adding URL. The problem does not happen when adding a path from hard disk.

Comment: May be you can't establish ssl connection because your sertificate is not trusted, this can happened even in case the certificate have placed into trusted root store, if for example name sertificate is different from your url ...

Comment: Try to check your certificate like desribed here https://medium.com/@sslsecurity/how-to-check-ssl-certificate-information-in-different-web-browsers-6185dbca221